# How can I stream video stored on one MacBook Pro to another?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, video

I have two MacBook Pro laptops, a 17-inch MBP and a 13-inch MBP. The 17-inch MBP is connected to an Elgato EyeTV HD Video Capture Recorder (and thence to a cable TV set top box). I use that to grab video off of my STB and to record live TV. The 13-inch MBP is my general purpose laptop, and I also want to use it for iOS and Android development.

Eventually I know I will get a RAID unit from Synology or a Drobo (in order to do automated redundant backups of the media on my 17-inch MBP and on the array of external HDDs that are connected to it), but not immediately since I'm trying to save money and pay down credit card debt, etc.

My question: without using sneakernet to copy the multi-gigabyte files over, or using remote control software like TeamViewer, or a LAN, is there a simple and cheap way to play back videos stored on my 17-inch MBP on my 13-inch MBP? Sort of like how you can use AirPlay or Google Chromecast to stream media from your phone to your TV or something?

Answer (score 1):

If the video is already recorded, you could just [share](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sharing-a-folder-in-mac-os-x-lion.html) the video folder with the other Mac. If you [connect](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-connect-to-a-shared-folder-on-a-remote-mac-.html) to the 17-inch MBP from your 13-inch and log in as the 17-inch MBP user, you can have access to all the users files. You can open the videos on the 13-inch MBP and play them in e.g. VLC player. Or you could share one folder only and set it to read only.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), A/K/A VLC. It has video [streaming capabilities](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) and, best of all, is free!

"On Mac OS X 10.4 or later, VLC is able to grab video and audio from EyeTV applications and therefore all EyeTV-compatible capture devices. The user needs to install a plugin to EyeTV.app in order to use this feature. Guidance is provided in the User Interface. Requires VLC 0.9.0 or later."

Comment: Could you explain how having VLC on my 13-inch MBP would enable me to play back videos that are stored on my 17-inch MBP though?

Comment: The 17" would stream to the 13", both Macs using VLC.

Comment: IconDaemon, a further clear explanation of how that would be possible would be gratefully received. Although the two MBPs are both using the same wifi network, they are not otherwise connected.

Comment: This [documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/) on the VLC wiki should help. I'd ask for particulars from my network guy, but he's on vacation in Patagonia and a _little_ hard to reach.

Comment: I've gone through that documentation and I do not think it is going to do what I want it to do. The media files are on one MBP and I want to play them back on another. Other than both of the machines using the same wifi signal the machines are not connected in any way. Your VLC streaming solution would work if the 1st MBP had an static IP that I could reference on the 2nd MBP, but I don't think that is the case.

Comment: You could certainly at least test if the concept would work. The dynamic IP of the streaming mac is easily found out before streaming. You can even [set a static IP](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/550) quite easily, even for wifi. Experiment! Learn from failure! We're rooting for you!

Comment: Haha! I will try it out and get back to you. Thanks for the encouragement! :)